# Grouping data in R based on specific column values

Tags: r

I have a set of data in a csv file that I need to group based on transitions of one column.  I'm new to R and I'm having trouble finding the right way to accomplish this.

Simplified version of data:

```
Time    Phase    Pressure    Speed
 1        0        0.015      0
 2       25        0.015      0
 3       25        0.234      0
 4       25        0.111      0
 5        0        0.567      0
 6        0        0.876      0
 7       75        0.234      0
 8       75        0.542      0
 9       75        0.543      0
```

The length of time that phase changes state is longer than above but I shortened everything to make it readable and this pattern continues on and on.  What I'm trying to do is calculate the mean of pressure and speed for each instance where the phase is non-zero. For example, in the output from the sample above there would be two lines, one with the average of the three lines where phase is 25, and with the average of the three lines when phase is 75. It will be possible to see cases where the same numeric value of phase shows up more than once, and I need to treat each of those separately. That is, in the case where phase is `0, 0, 25, 25, 25, 0, 0, 0, 25, 25, 0`, I would need to record the first group and the second group of 25s as separate events, as well as any other non-zero groups.

What i've tried:

```
`csv <- read.csv("c:\\test.csv")`
`ins <- subset(csv,csv$Phase == 25)`
`exs <- subset(csv,csv$Phase == 75)`
`mean(ins$Pressure)`
`mean(exs$Pressure)`
```

This obviously returns the average of the entire file when phase is 25 and 75, but I need to somehow split it into groups using the trailing and leading 0s.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `split(csv, cumsum(c(1, diff(csv$Phase) != 0)))`

Comment: I'm confused, what's the problem here? You are getting the means for when Phase is 25 and 75. Are you just trying to make it all into a single data frame? (Also, as an FYI, they recommend not using `subset` in programs - it is really only for interactive use.)

Comment: Can it happen that in the `phase` column you would have data like `0 0 25 25 0 0 25 25` and would like to calculate the mean for these phases `25` separately?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear.  Each group of 25s or 75s represents a distinct section of data.  They all need to be calculated separately.

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly, as you are really asking for something very different from aggregation by groups.

Comment: @user7780371 I tried to edit your question to make sure that it was reflecting what you are seeking, if I did not represent something correct, please make additional changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: Based on feedback from the asker, they are really seeking to do some aggregations across runs of numbers (i.e. the first group of continuous 25s, then the second group of continuous 25s, and so on). Because of that, I suggest using `rle` or the run-level encoding function, to get a group number that you can use in the `aggregate` command.

I've modified the original data so that it contains two runs of 25, just for illustrative purposes, but it should work regardless. Using `rle` we get the encoded runs of data, and then we create a group number for each row. We do this by getting a vector of the total number of observed lengths, and then using the `rep` function to repeat each one by the appropriate length.

After this is done, we can use the same basic aggregation command again.

```
df_example <- data.frame(Time = 1:9,
                         Phase = c(0,25,25,25,0,0,25,25,0),
                         Pressure = c(0.015,0.015,0.234,0.111,0.567,0.876,0.234,0.542,0.543),
                         Speed = rep(x = 0,times = 9))

encoded_runs <- rle(x = df_example$Phase)
df_example$Group_No <- rep(x = 1:length(x = encoded_runs$lengths),
                           times = encoded_runs$lengths)

aggregate(x = df_example[df_example$Phase != 0,c("Pressure","Speed")],
          by = list(Group_No = df_example[df_example$Phase != 0,"Group_No"],
                    Phase = df_example[df_example$Phase != 0,"Phase"]),
          FUN = mean)

  Group_No Phase Pressure Speed
1        2    25    0.120     0
2        4    25    0.388     0
```

Comment: To expand a bit, the file will end up having thousands of "groups" of non-zero numbers, where a 25 signals one part of the cycle, and 75 another.  The corresponding data for these groups though, as the pattern continues on and on, will be different.  This is why I'm trying to look at them as separate.  Is it possible to create a set containing the mean calculations for each group one by one?  So for instance group[1] contains the averages of the first group of 25s and group[2] does the same with 75 and so on all the way up to group[n]?  Does that make sense?

Comment: I have an idea for you. Please edit your question while I modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user7780371 I've updated my answer with something I think might work for you.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Super quick:

```
df <- read.csv("your_file_name.csv")

cbind(aggregate(Pressure ~ Phase, df[df$Phase != 0,], FUN = mean),
      aggregate(Speed ~ Phase, df[df$Phase != 0,], FUN = mean)[2])
```

The `cbind` is fancy - depending on the distribution of values of Phase, you'll need to `merge` instead.

Comment: This can be done much more quickly with a single `aggregate()` command, as shown below (or above, or wherever my answer gets put :D).

Answer (score 0):

Building upon comment by Solos, and answer by Cheesman,
try:

```
csv$block = paste(csv$Phase, cumsum(c(1, diff(csv$Phase) != 0)))

df_example = csv

aggregate(x = df_example[df_example$Phase != 0,c("Pressure","Speed")],
        by = list(Phase = df_example[df_example$Phase != 0,"block"]),
        FUN = mean)
```

actually `plyr` would be handy:

```
csv$block = paste(csv$Phase, cumsum(c(1, diff(csv$Phase) != 0)))

require(plyr)

ddply(csv[csv$Phase!=0,], .(block), summarize,
mean.Pressure=mean(Pressure), mean.Speed=mean(Speed))
```